# prevent automatic deletion of /etc/hosts entry

Tags: linux

I am using a Linux Ubuntu Precise 12.04 version.
I have added a virtual host entry in my /etc/hosts

```
XX.XX.XX.XX     www.domain-name.com
```

After sometime, this entry got deleted automatically. What could be the possible reason behind it? How do I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
chattr +i /etc/hosts
```

even root will not be allowed to remove or modify the file until you run :

```
chattr -i /etc/hosts
```

See [`man chattr`](http://tech-zilla.com/man_pages/ubuntu/1/chattr.html)

Comment: trying .. lets see after some time, if it works, thanks :)

Comment: Try this : `cp -a /etc/hosts /etc/hosts_20130220, rm -f /etc/hosts`, you will see immediately ;) ( or just try to modify the file )

Answer (score 2):

The hosts file is automatically generated by default in ubuntu 12.04. The way to stop this from happening is to make `/etc/hosts` a normal file instead of a symlink.

The easiest way to do this is to copy the file and move it back.

```
sudo cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.new
sudo rm /etc/hosts
sudo mv /etc/hosts.new /etc/hosts
```